# What is the difference between list.files and dir?

Tags: r

I tried using both `list.files` and `dir`; both commands returned the same output. What is the key difference between these two commands and what's their usage context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are identical in the sense that they take the same arguments, these arguments have identical defaults, and they use the same `.Internal` function to execute.

As pointed out by @RichScriven in the comments, a compact and accurate test that they are the same can be run using `identical`:

```
identical(list.files, dir)
[1] TRUE
```

We can also take a look at their source code.

```
dir
function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
    no.. = FALSE) 
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
    ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
<bytecode: 0x000000000fe1c388>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

and

```
list.files
function (path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, 
    no.. = FALSE) 
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
    ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
<bytecode: 0x0000000008811280>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Note that

```
.Internal(list.files(path, pattern, all.files, full.names, recursive, 
        ignore.case, include.dirs, no..))
```

is executed in both functions.

Comment: I wish they would say something about this in `?dir`. Spent 10 minutes playing "spot the difference" before finally convincing myself they're identical and googling to be extra-extra-sure

Comment: @MichaelChirico - You could have just done `identical(dir, list.files)`. ;)  It might be worth noting the result in this answer as well.

Comment: @RichScriven good point, though I don't have the instinct to try that on functions! I guess it's a vestige from S plus? I wish they gave some context on why both functions exist...

Comment: Thanks @RichScriven. I added this test to the top of the post.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Perhaps a hint is that there are two listed authors, one of the original "Rs" and also professor Ripley. Maybe one wrote a separate and then these were later merged. It would be useful to note their identical nature in the help page.

Comment: is it true that my understanding that list.files('c:/Program Files/Java') will return the contents of this directory even though my working directory is way different, where as dir() function will give the contents of current dir only? Because when I tried dir('c:/Program Files/Java'), it simply failed.

Comment: Take a look at the help file, `?dir`. This function accepts a path as its first argument. Also note Rich Scriven's comment that these two functions are actually identical objects. Most likely, there is a typo in your path. Maybe the first letter should be capitalized.